# Use UTC_TIMESTAMP() in $model->find Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, timestamp, utc

I would like to know how I can achieve this using the `CActiveRecord` in Yii:

`SELECT name, surname, UTC_TIMESTAMP(last_seen) FROM users WHERE id = '12345'`

I have already written most of my code using this method: `$model->findAll(...)`, but I cannot incorporate my favourite MySQL timestamp functions into the query.

I need this to be able to set the timezone using `date_default_timezone_set()` in PHP.

My timestamps are stored in the `TIMESTAMP` format in mysql table.

**EDIT**

I am not trying to pass the timezone to MySQL from PHP. I store my timestamp using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default value. The only time I want to use `date_default_timezone_set()` is when I want to display this date in the user's timezone.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough and I appreciate you input :-)

Comment: Something is buggy here, how you were thinking that the PHP timezone will be sent to MySQL? Look into findAllBySql and it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't understand what you mean by "how you were thinking that the PHP timezone will be sent to MySQL?". I did look at findAllBySql, but that will require me to convert all of my `$model->findAll()` into SQL statements. What I would like to know is whether or not there is a way to pass a `DATETIME` function into `$model->findAll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your recent comment, yes there is a way to pass [date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). If you check the [documentation of `findAll();`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail) can take 2 arguments, one for a condition or criteria, second for parameters to be bound to the generated sql.

We can use the first argument to pass a criteria and use [CDbCriteria's `select` property](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail), which

> refers to the select clause of an sql statement

And hence we can do:

```
$dbCriteria=new CDbCriteria;
$dbCriteria->select='name, surname, UTC_TIMESTAMP() as some_alias'; // we need the alias so that the timestamp is easily accessible
// you can also pass * if you need to access all the values of the table, alongwith the timestamp, like '*, UTC_TIMESTAMP() as some_alias'
$model->findAll($dbCriteria);
```

But ofcourse to use some_alias you'll need to declare it in your model:

```
public $some_alias; // this will be automatically be populated by the alias, when you query the db, in findAll
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to answer my own question. After further investigation, I realised I can just pass my select clause to the model where I define my relations like this:

`'users' => array(
                self::HAS_ONE, 'Users', 'user_id',
                'select' => 'user_id,firstname,lastname,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(usr_last_seen) AS usr_last_seen'
            ),`

But I think in the end, the do the same thing. So +1 to you!!

Comment: And sorry about the `UTC_TIMESTAMP`. I was actually looking for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, but in the end, the question was just about the way in which I can pass a MySQL function into my query (which you answered). Thanks :-)